# generating an .exe file using py2exe that generated .exe is not running if we place exe out side of dist folder

Tags: py2exe

when i generate .exe using py2exe one dist Folder will be created with exe and dependent dll and pyd files.this .exe will run only the exe is inside dist folder. Is it possible to generate the exe containg all dlls and pyds with it can run by placing anywhere in my system??

Comment: I suspect it is not possible to create an `exe` which can be placed anywhere, unless you could somehow tell it where the `dist` folder would always be located, as it needs to be able to find the `dll` and `pyd` files.

Comment: Something similar I would like to know is if you can create the `exe` in a different folder at all upon building, for example contain all dependencies in a folder next to the `exe`, if anyone knows?